# How to maintain the same position of 2 fixed divs?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create two `divs` that are positioned as `fixed` and set `left` and `bottom` values

```
<div id='div1'>test1</div>
<div id='div2'>test2</div>
```

I want thess divs to be lined up on the center

```
_________________________________________



              ____    ____
             |____|  |____|

_________________________________________
```

My css is as following

```
div#div1{
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    bottom: 48px;
    left: 35%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color:grey;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 500;
}
div#div2{
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    bottom: 48px;
    left: 55%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color:grey;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 500;
}
```

I also need these to be `fixed` position because I want them to stay on the same postion even though the user scrolls.

My problem is that I can't maintance the same distance from `left` to the `div` if I change the brower width or change to different screen.

so it could be like

```
___________________________________


        ____      ____
       |____|    |____|

___________________________________
```

If I have a smaller screen.

Can anyone help me to solve this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
 .wrapper{
  margin:0 auto;
  position:fixed;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-250px;
  bottom:48px;
  width:500px;
}


div#div1{
 float:left;
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color:grey;
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 500;
}

div#div2{
 float:right;
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color:grey;
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 500;
}
```